# Getting 404 error in azure-pipeline to fetch NPM packages from AZURE-ARTIFACT?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-artifacts

In azure-artifact we setup a "project scope" feed name "feed1" where we have NPM packages. This feed has been attached to "Project1".

Now my "Project2" pipeline is not able to fetch package from "feed1".

NOTE: All NPM packages exist in AZURE-ARTIFACT but still I'm getting 404 error.a

Answer (score 8):

> Now my "Project2" pipeline is not able to fetch package from "feed1".

Since that's a **project-scoped** feed within Project1, your Project2's pipeline can't find the package from `feed1` by default. It's **by design** behavior.

If you're using [Npm Install task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) to install the packages with this option:

[image]

Then you can try steps below to resolve that issue:

1.Go Organization Settings=>Settings(Pipelines) to **disable** `Limit job authorization scope to current project` option. (*Pipelines can run with collection scoped access tokens unless this option is enabled. With this option enabled, you can reduce the scope of access for all pipelines to the current project.*)

2.Then in **Project2**: Go Project Settings=>Settings(Pipelines) and **disable** `Limit job authorization scope to current project` option. So that `Project2`'s pipeline can access `project1`'s feed with collection scoped access token.

3.Run the **Project2**'s pipeline again, if the issue persists. Then check feed1's [feed settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#adding-usersgroups-permissions-to-a-feed):

- Add `Project2 Build Service` as `Contributor` role in `Permissions`.
- Edit the `Views`'s settings and make sure your Project2 can access them.

(If the missing package comes from local view/Upstream source, edit the Local view. If the missing package comes from PreRelease/Release view, edit corresponding views.)

[image]

Comment: Awesome.. I was going crazy with those 404 error from npm ci in Azure pipeline with the feed from a different project. I figured out it could be permissions issue and made sure the Build service - Contributor - Feed permission is all good. Only thing I was missing was the setting hidden under Project Settings - definitely a needle in a haystack. You really saved my day! Cheers