# Correct pipeline & feed settings/permissions

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

We are close to rolling out our first pilot of Azure pipelines and Azure Artifacts but I am (still) somehow lost with the right settings for pipelines and artifacts.

Our setup is the following.

Every Azure project has a feed where the pipelines of the multiple GIT repos within that project push their universal packages to.

The pipeline itself is consuming universal packages from feeds of the same but also other projects of the same ADO org.

Now I have seen the settings for pipelines "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-relase pipelines" and the feed settings "Organization and Project scope" and I do not know what to set to support our scenario. I have read the official documentation but somehow I am still not sure what to configure.

Can you help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which scope do you prefer, [Project-Scope feed or Organization-Scope feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables)?

**The biggest difference between them is:**

1.If you create a Org-scope feed in ProjectA, someone(If you grant Feed permissions to him) can view and manage the feed from any project within same org. It means people can view the feed details even in ProjectB.

2.If you create a Project-scope feed in ProjectA, then only members of ProjectA can view this feed via Artifacts page:

[image]

But as I know, they both works for your scenario no matter which scope you choose.

**So you have two directions:**

1.Create a org-scope feed in ProjectA, then configure the feed settings:

[image]

Then grant **Contributor** role to ProjectB Build Service and ProjectB Team:

[image]

So that members in ProjectB Team group(ProjectB Team) can see the feed in ProjectB's artifacts page, and the pipeline(ProjectB Build Service) can download/publish package from/to the feed.

2.Create project-scope feeds per project. ProjectA=>FeedA, ProjectB=>FeedB, ProjectC=>FeedC.

For scenario where ProjectA will push package to FeedA, and ProjectB/ProjectC will consume the package from FeedA: You can edit FeedA's feed settings, add corresponding role to `ProjectA build service, ProjectB Team and ProjectB build service, ProjectC Team and ProjectC build service`. Consuming package needs reader role while publishing package needs at least contributor role.

And normally you can **disable** `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-relase pipelines` option to avoid/resolve 404 error like [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336873/10910450).

Comment: OK. Thank you. 
Is there any way to make an org scoped feed again project scoped?
I have tried this by taking over the permission and view settings from a project-scoped feed to an org-scoped feed but in the feed selector drop down list one feed is still showing up as project-scoped whereas the other is still shown as org-scoped although both have the same permission and view settings.

Comment: One more last question: What about the access permissions in the views? Let's say the default "Local" view? What is the relation between the feed "Permissions" and the views "Access Permissions"?

Comment: For your first question, as I know there's no way to change existing project-scoped feed into org-scoped feed or change existing org-scoped feed into project-scoped feed. The permissions and view permissions are just permission-related settings, they have nothing to do with feed scope.(project scope or organization scope).

Comment: @Marko For you second question, a feed normally contains different views. When personA is allowed in feed `Permissions`, then he is one of the feed users that can access this feed. Since my feed has Local,PreRelease,Release views and their access permissions are `feed users` by default, PersonA can access the three views within the feed.

Comment: About the relationship between feed permissions and view access permissions: See last [important](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops#what-can-i-do-if-im-concerned-about-my-project-scoped-feeds-visibility):If a user have permission to a specific view, and even if they don't have permission to the feed, they will still be able to access and download packages through that view.

Comment: A can access Feed=>A can access all views within that feed by default. B can't access Feed, but he can access Local View=>Then B can access packages in local view within that feed, but he can't access other views in that feed. Feed permissions control who can access the feed and all Views within that while view access permission who can access current specific view.